# What is the purpose of using super in class initializer?

Tags: python, object

I was reading some Python code in a private repository on GitHub and found a class resembling the one below:

```
class Point(object):
    '''Models a point in 2D space. '''

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(Point, self).__init__()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    # some methods

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Point({}, {})'.format(self.x, self.y)
```

I do understand the importance and advantages of using the keyword `super` while initialising classes. Personally, I find the first statement in the `__init__` to be redundant as all the Python classes inherit from `object`. So, I want to know what are the advantages(if any) of initializing a `Point` object using `super` when inheriting from the base `object` class in Python ?

Comment: Some might claim it's safer for multiple inheritance, but slapping `super().__init__()` at the top of your `__init__` isn't nearly enough to ensure safe, correct behavior in a multiple inheritance situation; for example, the necessary arguments aren't likely to reach the `__init__` methods that need them. Multiple inheritance is *hard*.

Answer (score 1):

There is none in this particular case as `object.__init__()` is an empty method. However, if you were to inherit from something else, or if you were to use multiple inheritance, call to the `super.__init__()` would ensure that your classes get properly initialized (assuming of course they depend on initialization from their parent classes). Without that Python's MRO cannot do its *magic*, for example.